# Scapy is not found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, scapy

`from scapy.all import *`

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'

I have installed `scapy` through through `pip`. I have also downloaded `scapymaster` through their documentation, but when I try to run the `setup.py`, another error pops up as shown in screen shot below

[scapymaster installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hOy3.png)

I don't seem to find any viable solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you quoted is letting you know that the `scapy` module doesn't exist with the way you called it.

I'll give an example of how I did it with windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04. Install python 3 for your OS first.

Windows 10:

```
py -3 -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\pip install scapy
.\venv\Scripts\python <python script that imports scapy>.py
```

Ubuntu 20.04:

```
python3 -m venv venv
venv/bin/pip install scapy
venv/bin/python <python script that imports scapy>.py
```